# VBA Function - Remove Carriage Return and Line Breaks from Array - Code Review

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code which works well for removing invalid line breaks and carriage returns from an array containing a split string.

I am aware that this isn't the best way to write this code so would like to pass it to the community to suggest better practice.

Comments

Step 1: This function will take a string (strString) and load each individual character into the declared array (varStringArray).

Step 2: If the code finds any known Line breaks or carriage returns (Ascii code 10, 9 and 32), then it proceeds to re dimension the array, removing those characters in the process.  It will then set the boolean (bolReloop) to True, initiating a reloop.

Step 3: Once done, the new array is loaded to the function string.

Any suggestions from the community to execute this code more efficently without the need to reloop?

NOTE: Inbuilt excel functions do not work for this as they tend to miss most of the carriage returns and line breaks

```
    Function fnRemoveInvalidStrings(ByVal strString As String) As String
    Dim I                       As Long
    Dim J                       As Long
    Dim bolReloop               As Boolean
    Dim varStringArray()        As Variant
    
    ReDim varStringArray(Len(strString) - 1)

    'Step 1:
    
    For I = 1 To Len(strString)
        varStringArray(I - 1) = Mid$(strString, I, 1)
    Next I
    
    'Step 2:  
    Reloop:
    bolReloop = False
    
    For I = LBound(varStringArray) To UBound(varStringArray)
        If Asc(varStringArray(I)) = 10 Or Asc(varStringArray(I)) = 9 Or Asc(varStringArray(I)) = 32 Then
            For J = I To UBound(varStringArray) - 1
                varStringArray(J) = varStringArray(J + 1)
            Next J
            ReDim Preserve varStringArray(LBound(varStringArray) To UBound(varStringArray) - 1)
            bolReloop = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next I
    
    If bolReloop = True Then
        GoTo Reloop
    End If

    'Step 3:
    fnRemoveInvalidStrings = Join(varStringArray)
    fnRemoveInvalidStrings = Replace(fnRemoveInvalidStrings, " ", "")
    
End Function
```

Comment: Code review has it's own site and own posting rules: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  make sure you see their how to ask section.

Comment: But why not just do nested replaces: `fnRemoveInvalidStrings = Replace(Replace(Replace(strString,chr(10),""),Chr(9),""),Chr(32),"")))`

Comment: 13 = CR. 32 = a space.

Comment: _Inbuilt excel functions do not work for this as they tend to miss most of the carriage returns and line breaks_: Using `Replace` (or `Substitute` in an Excel formula) _will_ work.  Rather than asking us to improve a horrible work around, show us your original formual attempt, we'll help you fix that.

Comment: This question is on topic for both sites. :) [Please stop redirecting performance problems to Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388864/please-stop-redirecting-performance-problems-to-code-review) and [Performance question - Stack Overflow or Code Review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review) and [Guidance on migrating questions to Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348395/guidance-on-migrating-questions-to-code-review)

Comment: Even I used to think that but was later corrected. If one has enough reputation then you will be able to see the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390803/is-this-question-on-topic-for-code-review) that I had asked (now deleted)

Comment: Having said that, I agree with the lads above that a simple `Replace` will solve your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested, `Replace()` does the job quite fine. Here's a possible general purpose solution to get rid off unwanted characters/strings in a string:

```
Dim sTest As String, sResult As String
Dim asInvalid(1 To 4) As String

sTest = "G[[j:273l\ub4mxlS<g;mQgQohYd5V_tcHz3pg7N5lof6T=an01WFdTE=<CBnU;:m8bC?KTq?t2ItiTLB64QNT>NALC]VNfC7>mm8vJQ3R:68t:UM8ERe<\np:<?8Zx["

' Remove all occurances of '[', ';', '='  and 'an01WFdTE' from the string
asInvalid(1) = "["
asInvalid(2) = ";"
asInvalid(3) = "="
asInvalid(4) = "an01WFdTE"

sResult = RemoveInvalidStrings(sTest, asInvalid())

Debug.Print "Source: "; sTest
Debug.Print "Len(Source): "; Len(sTest)
Debug.Print "Result: "; sResult
Debug.Print "Len(Result): "; Len(sResult)


' Removes characters considered to be 'invalid' from a string
' sSource - source string
' asInvalidStrings() - list of invalid characters/strings
Function RemoveInvalidStrings(ByVal sSource As String, asInvalidStrings() As String) As String
   
   Dim i As Long
   
   For i = LBound(asInvalidStrings) To UBound(asInvalidStrings)
      Do While InStr(sSource, asInvalidStrings(i)) > 0
         sSource = Replace(sSource, asInvalidStrings(i), vbNullString)
      Loop
   Next i

   RemoveInvalidStrings = sSource
   
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a function to clean the input string. You may want to consider the following function instead?

```
Function CleanTrim(ByVal Text As String, Optional ConvertNonBreakingSpace As Boolean = True) As String
    ' https://excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/155-Trim-all-Cells-in-a-Worksheet-VBA#post1092
    ' Code modified from that by Rick Rothstein
    Dim i As Long, CodesToClean As Variant
    CodesToClean = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, _
                         21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157)
    If ConvertNonBreakingSpace Then Text = Replace(Text, Chr(160), " ")
    For i = LBound(CodesToClean) To UBound(CodesToClean)
        If InStr(Text, Chr(CodesToClean(i))) Then Text = Replace(Text, Chr(CodesToClean(i)), "")
    Next i
    CleanTrim = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Text)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input, I took examples from both Tragamor, Scott Craner and Hel O'Ween.

This resulted in the much improved code below, thank you all for your contribution and input!

```
Function fnRemoveCarriageReturns(ByVal strString As String) As String

Dim varChrArray(2) As String
varChrArray(0) = Chr(9)
varChrArray(1) = Chr(10)
varChrArray(2) = Chr(13)

Dim I As Long

fnRemoveCarriageReturns = strString

For I = LBound(varChrArray) To UBound(varChrArray)
    If InStr(1, strString, varChrArray(I)) Then
       fnRemoveCarriageReturns = Replace(strString, varChrArray(I), "")
    End If
Next I

End Function
```

Comment: Here's a tip: whenever you need to solve a _specific_ problem, in this case remove tabs, LFs and CRs from a string, try to figure out if the solution to your problem can be made more generic, covering other use cases in the future. Like I did with my suggestion: It's not limited to certain (hard-coded) strings/characters, but can be used in the future whenever something needs to be removed from a string. And another advice: VBA has a couple builtin [string constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/miscellaneous-constants). Try to use these.